# Can Mad-Eye Moody control how much his eye sees?

Tags: harry-potter, alastor-moody

Mad-Eye Moody's iconic magic eye is one of the most interesting magical modifications applied to a wizard in the Harry Potter series.

For example, the Yule Ball:

> “Nice socks. Potter,” Moody growled as he passed, his magical eye staring through Harry's robes.
>
> ***Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 23, "The Yule Ball"***

This really triggered my imagination. My question is: Can Moody control how much his eye sees (as in moving the view in between different floors, etc.)

Comment: My question is not the "if it sees too much". I am asking if he can control how much his eyes see. I apologize if there was confusion when it came to what I was asking, and have removed the opinion-based question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Probably**

In *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, the order (IIRC Molly Weasley) asks Moody to look into a writing desk to see if there's a boggart in it.  At the time they are in the kitchen, and the desk is in the upstairs drawing room.  Moody mutters "Drawing room" and then instructs the eye to look at the "Desk in the corner" where he then proceeds to tell Molly there is a boggart inside.

The pragmatic implication here is that Moody's eye cannot see into the drawing room unless Moody specifically wishes it.  Then it see through the ceiling into the drawing room, but cannot see inside the writing desk until Moody tells it to.  Of course there are other explanations to this order of operations, (maybe the eye's view of the room didn't include the corner, maybe it showed everything but Moody needed a "closer look" to identify the boggart, etc.) but there are no other situations I can think of that show Moody's eye being limited by anything other than the normal field of vision for an eye.  (As evidenced by the eye spinning around in its socket on numerous occasions when Moody seems to want a 360-degree view of his surroundings.)

Comment: If you are correct, it really makes one wonder why he specifically _wanted_ to look at Harry's socks...

Comment: I take the view of Lavender Brown FreeMan. That eye should NOT have been allowed.  I didn't put it in the answer because it's pure speculation, but my guess is the eye has "levels" of automatic see-through.  So Moody doesn't auto-see-through a wall across a room, because it's unlikely an attack would come through a wall 50ft away. But it can see through someone's robes 2ft away from him because Moody's super paranoid.  let's not think to deeply about what that means for Moody's view of all the underaged students/other people he interacts with.

Comment: Sounds like the "xray vision" glasses they used to sell in ads in the back of _Boys Life_ and comic books... LOL

Comment: Great first answer!

Comment: @FreeMan Maybe Barty Crouch likes socks (sort of like Dumbledore).